# Prerequisites for generalized linear models class

Tags: generalized-linear-model, references, linear-model

I am considering taking a course in generalized linear models at an American university this year. I have good knowledge of probability at the level of [Ross](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9332519072) and also [Tsitsiklis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/188652923X) . My calculus and linear algebra knowledge I am quite confident in. For any instructors of such classes or students that have taken the class, do you think I have the proper background for such a class? The class follows the textbook by [McCullagh and Nelder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412317605) which I've began reading and find it moderately challenging but still unsure if the course will require more statistics background from me.

Comment: Besides probability courses have you taken any other statistics courses? If not I would think you should take a linear models course at the least, and have a solid understanding of many basic statistical techniques (ANOVA, OLS, etc) or else you won't know why "generalizing" matters.

Answer (score 1):

Having both taken and taught (to some degree) classes on linear models, I can tell you that an introductory statistics course is a recommended prereq.

I looks like your probability courses are lacking a few important fundamentals like hypothesis testing and distributions.